# Indexing HTML div classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to compare two values of different div classes using the data attribute.  I have multiple div classes like these two, all with different data-vale:

```
<div class="card" data-value=38>
    <img class ="front-face" src= "PNG/QH.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="card" data-value=39>
    <img class ="front-face" src= "PNG/KH.png"/>
  </div>
```

Every div class will also receive a unique order using cards.style.order

In a JS function the user will select two cards (firstCard,secondCard) and the function should check if the value of firstCard is one greater than the value of the card with order 1 more than secondCard.

Here is the code I have been trying to use:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

if(firstCard.dataset.value === cards[cards.indexOf(secondCard)-1].dataset.value)
```

cards is an array housing all of my div classes.  One of the errors I received told my that indexOf is not a usable function here.  I think this may be because the div classes are not actually part of an array and I need a different method to find the 'value of' something rather than the 'index of'.

For example, if a row of cards goes 2D,7S,9D,8H,3D,  the user can click 3D for firstCard and 7S for secondCard.  The function will verify that the value of 3D is one greater than 2D and will swap the positions of 3D and 7S.

Comment: 1. Can you use jQuery?
2. Can you please explain again what is the desired behaviour? You just want to compare the `data-value` of the `firstCard` with `data-value` of the `secondCard`?

Comment: If you know that all of then have different data-value, why to check if is different or not? It will be always different, right?

Comment: I can use JQuery.  I attempted to use a .previousSibling method but that did not work either.

Comment: The way the game would work a player would select two cards firstCard = 5D secondCard = 9S.  The function would check if we should change the position of firstCard and secondCard.  The cards should be swapped if the card before the 9S is the 4D.  So my function should check if firstCard comes sequentially after the card before secondCard.

Comment: @Calvin Nunes For example, if a row of cards goes 2D,7S,9D,8H,3D,  the user can click 3D for firstCard and 7S for secondCard.  The function will verify that the value of 3D is one greater than 2D and will swap the positions of 3D and 7S.

Comment: @user8735495 do you use AngularJS or just pure javascript? (and/or jQuery).

Comment: @Adi I haven't learned AngularJS yet so I am trying to do this using only JS and jQuery.

Comment: @user8735495 Are the cards hardcoded in your HTML or do you generate them automatically from js?

Comment: @Adi they are all hard coded in HTML

Comment: Would be possible to you to provide an example with less cards, (5 for example), that way we would have a better visualization of the current functionality and desired result? (using jsFiddle or snippet)

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Exactly as said by @undefined  and me, provide jsFiddle or snippet, don't post code in comments, it's terrible to read

Comment: @Calvin Nunes
My jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tdammon/y06dwvfc/4/
In this program I have modified the moveCard function.  If you select 3C and then 2C these cards will switch places.  What I actually want to happen is the user will select 3C and then the card immediately to the right of 2C and the program will switch 3C and whatever card is immediately to the right of 2C.  The user will never actually select 2C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made my little snippet with auto-generating squares that can be moved as you suggested. You might check it out. If something is not okay, you might point it out, maybe I forgot something.

```js
let cardsArray = [{
  "value": 7,
  "color": "red"
 }, {
   "value": 6,
   "color": "yellow"
 }, {
   "value": 5,
   "color": "green"
 }, {
   "value": 4,
   "color": "red"
 }, {
   "value": 3,
   "color":  "yellow"
 }, {
   "value": 2,
   "color": "green"
 }, {
   "value": 1,
   "color": "green"
}]

// Function to automatically generate some squares
function drawSquares() {
  let squaresParent = $("#squaresParent");
  squaresParent.empty();
  let lCALen = cardsArray.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < lCALen; ++i) { //make it efficient for checking length
    // Creating a text object for display purposes only
    let newText = $('<p>').append(cardsArray[i].value);
    
    // Creating a new card
    let newCard = $('<div>').attr({
      'data-value': cardsArray[i].value,
      'style': 'background-color:' + cardsArray[i].color,
      'index': i,
      'class': 'card'
      }).append(newText);
      
    squaresParent.append(newCard);
  }
}

drawSquares();
assignEvents();

let firstCard = null;
let secondCard = null;

function compareAndMove(fC, sC) {
  //console.log("Switching...");
  
  let firstCardIndex = fC.attr("index");
  let secondCardIndex = sC.attr("index");
  
  let beforeSecondCardIndex = 0;
  if (secondCardIndex > 0)
    beforeSecondCardIndex = secondCardIndex - 1;
  
  let firstCard = cardsArray[firstCardIndex];
  let secondCard = cardsArray[secondCardIndex];
  let beforeSecond = cardsArray[beforeSecondCardIndex];

  if (firstCard.value - 1 === beforeSecond.value) {
    let temp = firstCard;
    cardsArray[firstCardIndex] = secondCard;
    cardsArray[secondCardIndex] = temp;
    
    drawSquares();
    assignEvents();
  } else {
    fC.removeClass("selected");
    sC.removeClass("selected");
  }
  
  //console.log("Exiting...");
}

function assignEvents() {
  $(".card").click(function() {
    //console.log("Card clicked");

    if (!firstCard) {
      firstCard = $(this);
      firstCard.addClass("selected");
      return;
    }

    if (!secondCard) {
      secondCard = $(this);
      secondCard.addClass("selected");
    }

    compareAndMove(firstCard, secondCard);
    firstCard = null;
    secondCard = null;
  });
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.selected {
 border: 3px solid black;
}

body {
  background-color: #ABCDEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
      <div id="squaresParent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This allows me to swap any two squares.  The swapping should only take place if the the first square selected is one larger than the square immediately to the left of the second square selected.

Comment: @user8735495 I accidentaly used "<" instead of "===". Check it again.

Comment: This works as I want my program to.  What determines the order the elements are displayed?  Is it the order they appear in the array?

Comment: Yes, by default they are as I declared them in the array. If I want to swap them, I change their order in the initial array and then I redraw them. Of course, this might be done more efficient by swapping only the selected elements, but let's consider this as a homework maybe .
@user8735495 If you like my answer, you might mark it :D Cheers!

Comment: @user8735495 No problem, anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this..

```js
var currentCard = $(".cards").first();
var currentCardInd = $(currentCard).attr("index");

$(".cards").on("click", function(event){
    if(currentCard && parseInt(currentCardInd) < parseInt($(this).attr("index"))){
      currentCard.attr("index", $(this).attr("index"));
      $(this).attr("index", currentCardInd.toString());
      $(this).swapWith(currentCard);
      currentCard = $(".cards[index='"+$(this).attr("index")+"']").next();
      currentCardInd = $(currentCard).attr("index");
    }
});


jQuery.fn.swapWith = function(_with) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var copyWith = $(_with).clone(true);
        var copyOrig = $(this).clone(true);
        $(_with).replaceWith(copyOrig);
        $(this).replaceWith(copyWith);
    });
};
```

```css
.cards{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-radius:5px;
}

#card-7S{
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
#card-9D{
  background-color:lightyellow;
}
#card-8H{
  background-color:lightgray;
}
#card-3D{
  background-color:lightpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="card-2d" class="cards" index="2">2D</div>
  <div id="card-7S" class="cards" index="4">7S</div>
  <div id="card-9D" class="cards" index="7">9D</div>
  <div id="card-8H" class="cards" index="10">8H</div>
  <div id="card-3D" class="cards" index="15">3D</div>
</div>
```

You can also check here..
https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/7z3y8mb5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that querySelectorAll() returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which behave as an array but it is not really an array.

The same problem happens with getElementsByClassName() this one return an HTMLCollection which behave as an array but does not include all the prototypes functionalities since it is not really an array.

So you have several options to get the index, after getting the index you can get the element that is before it.

**Use call or apply to trick the Array methods**

```
`Array.prototype.indexOf.call(cards, second)`
```

**Iterate manually**

```
`let selectedIndex = 0;
for(let i =0; i < cards.length; i++){
  if(cards[i] === second){
    selectedIndex = i;
  }
};
console.log(selectedIndex)`
```

**Create an array using cards NodeList**

`const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
   const cardsArray = Array.from(cards)
  if(firstCard.dataset.value === 
  cardsArray[cardsArray.indexOf(secondCard)-1].dataset.value)`

**Use any library to select the element that returns an array, as jQuery**

Comment: I don't want to compare the firstCard and secondCard.  I want to compare the firstCard and the card directly before secondCard.  If the condition is met between those two than the code will switch the positions of firstCard and secondCard.  An example with an array might help [1,2,6,9,8,4,7].  If the user selects 7 for firstCard and 9 for secondCard, the code will check that 7 is one larger than 6.  The code will than swap the positions of the firstCard and secondCard so the new array will be [1,2,6,7,8,4,9]

Comment: What if second card is exactly the first one? @user8735495

Comment: @Adi nothing would run in that instance.

Comment: I updated the answer, pointing out the issue with your code and possible solutions

Comment: Reviewing your code shared on jsfiddle you are overusing indexOf and some other array methods. Since accessing the method using the prototype and call to trick the methods is going to be a lot of trouble. My suggestion is review and clean the code, then after getting the cards, convert them to a real array so that you can use any Array methods: `const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');   const cardsArray = Array.from(cards);`

Answer (score 0):

`Array.from` is the canonical way to get an array of elements

```
<div class="card" data-value="38">
  <img class="front-face" src="PNG/QH.png"/>
</div>

<div class="card" data-value="39">
  <img class="front-face" src="PNG/KH.png"/>
</div>

<script>
  const [first, second] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card'))
  if (first.dataset.value === second.dataset.value) {
    /* do your thing... */
  }
</script>
```